# Dtreeviz - Same feature on tree level

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, dtreeviz

So I used dtreeviz to get a better view of my decision tree, I quadruple checked all the data, model and everything I did before plotting the decision tree, but [when looking at it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6D9t.png), we can see on the first level of the tree, that the two features are the same.

I wanted to know if this is ok, or is there an issue with my viz ?

Here is the code for tree plotting :

```
viz = dtreeviz(tree_model,
               X,
               np.array(y),
               target_name='pairingStatus',
               feature_names=features,
               class_names=tree_model.classes_.tolist()
              )
```

Comment: The features may be the same, but the splitting value is different

Comment: But how does it choose the split ?

Comment: Due to the preceding (root) node. there is no *single* sample ending up in both nodes; the left node consists of samples where `widthS63R04 <= 0.06`, while the right one of samples where `widthS63R04 > 0.06`. Given that, the fact that the 2nd node layer consists of the same attribute (here `chordS67R04`) does not infer any collusion. Try to "simulate" mentally a couple of samples as they "move" down the tree to convince yourself that it is so (we cannot do it ourselves since we don't have any sample of your data).